# Angular: No provider for depenency of dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner

I am building a small toy app in Angular, which has the following classes (among others): `ProductDetailComponent`, and `ProductService`. The service contains a method for making an http GET request for a product. The compnent displays the details of a product, and uses the service to retrieve the product information. After adding the `HttpModule` to the application (and to the service within it), my component tests are failing, saying "Error: No provider for Http!".

If I import the `HttpModule`, the tests pass again. However, I'm confused as to why it needs `HttpModule` in the first place, because that is a `ProductService` dependency, and I am mocking out the `ProductService` using a provider.

So my question in short is why do the tests tell me I need this dependency when the class under test does not use it?

**product-detail.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";
import {ProductService} from "../product.service";
import {Product} from "../product";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-detail',
  templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.css'],
  providers: [ProductService]
})
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  product: Product;

  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.productService.getProduct(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(product => this.product = product);
  }
}
```

**product.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Product} from "./product";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  private products: Product[];

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getProducts(): Promise<Product[]> {
    return this.http
      .get('/api/products/')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Product[])
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error)
      });
  }

  getProduct(id: number): Promise<Product> {
    return this.http
      .get(`/api/products/${id}`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Product)
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error)
      });
  }
}
```

**product-detail.component.spec.ts:**

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {ProductDetailComponent} from "./product-detail.component";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {ProductService} from "../product.service";
import {Product} from "../product";
import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {DebugElement} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";

describe('ProductDetailComponent', () => {
  let component: ProductDetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductDetailComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let element: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProductDetailComponent],
      //imports: [HttpModule], //un-commenting this fixes the breakages
      providers: [{
        provide: ActivatedRoute,
        useValue: {params: Observable.from([{'id': 1}])},
      }, {
        provide: ProductService,
        useValue: {
          getProduct: (id: number) => Promise.resolve(new Product(id, 'Example Product Name', 20))
        }
      }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductDetailComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be stable', () => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(fixture.isStable()).toBe(true);
    });
  });

  it('should display the title', () => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.name'));
      element = debugElement.nativeElement;
      expect(element.textContent).toEqual('Example Product Name')
    });
  });

  it('should display the price', () => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.span'));
      element = debugElement.nativeElement;
      expect(element.textContent).toEqual('$ 20.0')
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

- import `HttpModule` to your `NgModule`
- set ProductService as a provider in `NgModule` or `ProductDetailComponent`

For example:
product.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ProductDetailComponent } from './product-detail.component';
import { ProductService } from 'product.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProductDetailComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ProductService
  ],
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your module you have to add the `ProductService` provider to your providers property :

providers: [ProductService]